# How to list columns of a table in Bigtable?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bigtable

`cbt -instance=INSTANCE ls table` lists column families, but I want to list columns themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column families are explicitly created at the table level, while columns are dynamic and can be completely different per row. So, a general purpose tool to list columns is not necessarily possible.

You can write something for your particular needs using a client library in your language of choice, or parse the output of `cbt read` or `cbt lookup` command which lets you read every column in one or more rows.

The [Quickstart Using CBT](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/quickstart-cbt) page has examples of using these commands and the output they create.

Answer (score 2):

`cbt ls` will print all the tables in your current project and instance.

`cbt ls <table_name>` will list all the column families for that particular table.

Make sure that you have set the project and instance in this case by creating the `.cbtrc` file. You can find how to set that up [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-overview#create-cbtrc)